# How to toggle an element in array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, toggle

Here is my code for javascript for this simple task:

1. **Remove** the element if it exists in an array.
2. **Add** the element if it is not in an array.

   ```
   if(_.contains(this.types,type_id)){
       var index = this.types.indexOf(type_id);
       this.types.splice(index,1);
   }
   else{
       this.types.push(type_id);
   }
   ```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: can you be sure the element is there only once at most ?

Comment: Yes, one element should be only once in array

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you care about efficiency then may be using an array to implement a set is a bad idea. For example using an object you could do:

```
function toggle(S, x) {
    S[x] = 1 - (S[x]|0);
}
```

then after many add/remove operations you can keep only keys where the value is 1

This way every addition/removal is `O(1)` and you need only one `O(n)` operation to get the final result.

If keys are all "small" numbers may be a bitmask is even worth the effort (not tested)

```
function toggle(S, x) {
    var i = x >> 4;
    S[i] = (S[i]|0) ^ (1<<(x&15));
}
```

Comment: +1 for 0(1) possibility, if only we knew what the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 67):

You could do it without a 3rd party library, this would be more efficient, like this. (this only removes the first instance of a value if found, not multiple)

Javascript

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    b = 5,
    c = 6;

function addOrRemove(array, value) {
    var index = array.indexOf(value);

    if (index === -1) {
        array.push(value);
    } else {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

console.log(a);

addOrRemove(a, b);
console.log(a);

addOrRemove(a, c);
console.log(a);
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 5]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwVFy/)

Comment: This answer is ill-advised. A third-party library is not inherently less efficient than your own code. In fact, it is generally *more* efficient with developer resources since you don't need to reinvent the wheel. On top of that, the code shown here has the same suboptimal asymptotic complexity. The accepted answer by 6502, which actually achieves optimal complexity, is much better.

Answer (score 49):

For **immutable** state ( clone array ):

```
const addOrRemove = (arr, item) => arr.includes(item) ? arr.filter(i => i !== item) : [ ...arr, item ];
```

see also:
[Remove properties from objects (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/remove-properties-from-objects-javascript/56030135#56030135)

Comment: Dont you mean Array.includes?

Comment: @SKuijers .includes is a a prototype array method so it's used directly on the array

Answer (score 46):

### Using `lodash` "xor" function

```
_.xor([2, 1], [2, 3]);
// => [1, 3]
```

If you don't have an array as 2nd parameter you can simpy wrap the variable into an array

```
var variableToInsertOrRemove = 2;
_.xor([2, 1], [variableToInsertOrRemove]);
// => [1]
_.xor([1, 3], [variableToInsertOrRemove]);
// => [1, 2, 3]
```

Here's the doc: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#xor

Comment: Amazing and very clean method! Thanks 

Comment: Do note that this returns a new array instead of modifying the original array.

Answer (score 5):

Look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765477/2179748)** of similar question.

[Lodash issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1677)

[Lodash gist](https://gist.github.com/chodorowicz/1a77655681a3f67ea36de974a1357882/)

**Code:**

```
function toggle(collection, item) {
  var idx = collection.indexOf(item);
  if (idx !== -1) {
    collection.splice(idx, 1);
  } else {
    collection.push(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just a copy of Xotic750's answer with renamed variables.

Comment: This is not a Xotic750 answer! Please read my answer more attentively! The idea was taken from @nnnnnn answer but not Xotic750! And I mentioned it in my answer in the 1st link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765477/2179748) !

Answer (score 2):

If "types" can be a Set then

```
let toggle = type_id => this.types.delete(type_id) || this.types.add(type_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using underscorejs

```
function toggle(a,b)
{
return _.indexOf(a,b)==-1?_.union(a,[b]):_.without(a,b);
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4];
a = toggle(a,b); // [1,2,3,4]
a = toggle(a,b); // [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending [Xotic750's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17153457/9921110) this will always ensure that toggled elements occur **only once** in array. You this if your arrays are bit random like user inputs.

```js
function toggleValueInArray(array, value) {
  var index = array.indexOf(value);

  if (index == -1) {
    array.push(value);
  } else {
    do {
      array.splice(index, 1);
      index = array.indexOf(value);
    } while (index != -1);
  }
}


var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  b = 5,
  c = 10;

// toString just for good output
console.log(a.toString());

toggleValueInArray(a, b);
console.log(a.toString());

toggleValueInArray(a, c);
console.log(a.toString());
```