# Toggle values into and out of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to have a simple array of values, ie

```
var simpleArray = ["SE1","SE2","SE3"];
```

I want to check this array when an action happens (a click on a google map layer), that will pass a value to this function and either add the value to the array, or remove it from the array if it already exists.

I am now just a bit confused having seen .splice/push/inArray/indexOf (that doesn't work in IE)/grep (jQuery) - not sure what the best practice is.

Comment: You could take a look at http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming the order of the items doesn't matter you can do something like this:

```
function toggleArrayItem(a, v) {
    var i = a.indexOf(v);
    if (i === -1)
        a.push(v);
    else
        a.splice(i,1);
}
```

The [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) does work in IE from version 9 onwards, but if you need to support older IE versions you can use a shim as explained at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility). Or if you're using jQuery anyway use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inArray/) instead.

Answer (score 7):

my ES* variant

```
const toggleArrayValue = (arrayList, arrayValue) =>
  arrayList.includes(arrayValue)
    ? arrayList.filter(el => el !== arrayValue)
    : [...arrayList, arrayValue]
```

Answer (score 6):

extremely compact lodash version, using [xor function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xor), which is used to create a new array of values found only in one array and not the other

```
xor(array, [valueYouWantToToggle])
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if the value is an object:

```
const eq = (a, b) => a == b

const toggle = (arr, item) => {
  const resultArray = [];
  let duplicate = false;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(!eq(arr[i], item)) {
      resultArray.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      duplicate = true
    }
  }
  if(!duplicate) {
    resultArray.push(item)
  }
  return resultArray;
}
```